# How can I properly print a 10x10 grid in C?

Tags: c

I have a problem regarding something I am trying to create in C. I am a beginner and essentially I am trying to print a 10x10 grid of characters, it's supposed to be a level for a "Sokoban" game project that we have to program (all terminal-based). The map will be read from a txt file. This is the map I am trying to print:

```
##########
##########
#### o o##
####  ####
###   ####
##  x ####
#    o####
# xx P####
###  #####
##########
```

The '#'s represent walls, x represents a box, o represents the block where the box is supposed to be in, and P is the player.

Now whenever I print this in the terminal this is what gets output:

[image]

why is this the case? this is my code for printing and drawing the map:

```
typedef struct {              
    char grid[10][10];     
    Location player;
    bool win;

} Map;

Map m;
FILE* file;
// scanning from file
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                fscanf(file, "%c", &m.grid[i][j]);
            }
        }

// drawing map

void drawMap(Map m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            printf("%c", m.grid[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for any information you can give me. I'm thinking it has to do with the return character /0 but I can't seem to find the issue...

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step ⏯️ carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point? You have a well-defined failure point here.

Comment: What are the actual contents of the file?

Comment: The file contains this:

######################## o o######  #######   ######  x #####    o##### xx P#######  ###############

I will try the debugger and come back once I identify where it breaks

Comment: Please edit the question adding a [mre] and the verbatim content of the input file as text.

Comment: @RealBluenerve, from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77622766/how-can-i-properly-print-a-10x10-grid-in-c#comment136844868_77622766),  "######################## o o###### ####### ###### x ##### o##### xx P####### ###############" appears to be is 92 characters.  I'd expect at least 100 for a 10x10 grid.  What is the input file's true length?

Comment: Please provide a MRE (See Bob_s comment) and the output you get if you output each returned value from each call to `fsanf()`. Note, never ignore the return value of scanf&Co if anything seems weird.

Comment: @RealBluenerve The file content you showed in the comment above doesn't match that of the map you aim to draw. If the file actually contained the data for the target map, the rest of the program would read and draw it correctly.

Comment: An unrelated suggestion: Don't send in the `Map` by value like you do here: `void drawMap(Map m)`. That will copy the whole map. Take a pointer to the `Map` instead: `void drawMap(const Map *m)`

Comment: Better yet, output the row and column index, the returned value and the scanned character value during reading the file. Put the output of the scanned character within "<c>" to make emptys and blanks visible and discernable.

Comment: @RealBluenerve --  Your file must be munged because [look how perfectly your ```drawMap()``` function works](https://godbolt.org/z/c7Ys97PYE)

Comment: @RealBluenerve -- and of course I think you already know that 100 characters must be in the file (as chux mentioned), and *all of them must be on one line* -- else the linefeeds ('\n') will ruin the file read operation.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `fgetc()` function instead of `fscanf()`.

```
int row = 0, column = 0;
int c;
while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF && row < 10) {
    if (c != '\n') {
        m.grid[row][column] = c;
        column++;
    } else {
        row++;
        column = 0;
    }
}
```